# How can I access to a dynamic created array of labels

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I created an array of labels on runtime. Now i have a problem to access these labels from other functions.

Dynamic creation:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label[] Calendar_Weekday_Day = new Label[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        Calendar_Weekday_Day[i] = new Label();
        Calendar_Weekday_Day[i].Location = 
                                    new System.Drawing.Point(27 + (i * 137), 60);
        Calendar_Weekday_Day[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(132, 14);
        Calendar_Weekday_Day[i].Text = "Montag, 01.01.1970";
        this.TabControl1.Controls.Add(Calendar_Weekday_Day[i]);
    }
}
```

And the function where I want to access to the dynamic created array of labels:

```
private void display_weather_from_db(DateTime Weather_Startdate)
{
    Calendar_Weekday_Day[0].Text = "Test1";
    Calendar_Weekday_Day[1].Text = "Test2";
}
```

Error shown:

> The name 'Calendar_Weekday_Day' does not exist in the current
>   context   Form1.cs    1523    25  Test

I tryed this, but didn't help :(

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Label[] Calendar_Weekday_Day;
}
```

Someone an idea?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need just

```
Calendar_Weekday_Day = new Label[7];
```

instead of

```
Label[] Calendar_Weekday_Day = new Label[7];
```

in your `Form_Shown`. As it's written now, you are storing the list into a local variable instead of the instance field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely scope or lack of initialization. `Calendar_Weekday_Day` only exists within the `Form1_Shown` context. If you try to access it from another method, you're not going to be able to see it (and when it's private it's still not initialized to adding new elements is going to be problematic). You have two options:

- Change the scope (make `Calendar_Weekday_Day` a private property in the form's class and don't forget to initialize it)
- Search for the control by accessing `this.TabControl1.Controls`

You may also be better off using `private IEnumerable<Label> Calendar_WeekendDay` or maybe even `IList<Label>` to give you a little more flexibility with accessing the controls later.

Answer (score 0):

Remove redeclaration

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar_Weekday_Day = new Label[7]; // removed Label[]
```

... the rest is the same

this will be the smallest change required but you should be paying attention to compiler warnings. it most likely warned you that you redeclared field.

Answer (score 0):

if your tabcontrol contains only the labels so

```
 private void display_weather_from_db(DateTime Weather_Startdate)
 {
 Label[] Calendar_Weekday_Day = this.TabControl1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();

 Calendar_Weekday_Day[0].Text = "Test1";
 Calendar_Weekday_Day[1].Text = "Test2";

 }
```

if there is more other labels you have to filter, so first

```
  for .....
   ... _Day[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(132, 14);
    Calendar_Weekday_Day[i].Text = "Montag, 01.01.1970";
    Calendar_Weekday_Day[i].Tag= "Weather";// specify your label tag
    this.TabControl1.Controls.Add(Calendar_Weekday_Day[i]);
  ....
```

then

```
 private void display_weather_from_db(DateTime Weather_Startdate)
 {
 Label[] Calendar_Weekday_Day = this.TabControl1.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(X=>X.Tag!=null && X.Tag=="Weather").ToArray();


 Calendar_Weekday_Day[0].Text = "Test1";
 Calendar_Weekday_Day[1].Text = "Test2";

 }
```